# Mongoose is not executing the update operation properly

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So this is what I have and it seems like it doesn't execute the queries properly. Sometimes it on increases values for 1-2 documents, sometimes for all. I don't understand why does it behave like that. I have really been struggling with this problem and trying to find a solid solution.

This is the code that I have right now.

```
let lastPosition = req.body.pos;
let currentTopic = req.body.topic;

switch (lastPosition) {
    case 1:
        Post.updateMany( { position: { $in: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] }, active: true }, { $inc: { position : 1 } } )
        .exec(function() {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: "All positions from 3 to 6 pushed!",
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
           console.log(err);
        });
    case 2:
        // There are 5 more cases like that every other with one less element inside $in operator
}
```

Comment: Since you have a sequence I would think it would make more sense to just use:
`Post.updateMany({ position: {$gte: 1, $lte: 6}, active: true}, {$inc: { position: 1 }})`

Comment: Are you maybe closing the connection right after this?

Comment: @JohnnyHK and sometimesI get this error: `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` I get an error for every case, not only for the one it ends up to.

Comment: @Akrion Didn't change a thing. Same problems still occur.